# create new column group by values of other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I Have the following dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['A', "A", "A", "A", 'A', 'B', "B", 'B'], 'entity': ['Stay home', "Stay home", "WAY", "WAY", "Stay home", 'Go outside', "Go outside", "purpose"], 'token' : ['Severe weather', "raining", "smt", "SMT0", "Windy", 'Sunny', "Good weather", "smt"]
})


    sentence        entity      token
0   A               Stay home   Severe weather
1   A               Stay home   raining
2   A               Way         smt
3   A               Way         SMT0
4   A               Stay home   Windy
5   B               Go outside  Sunny
6   B               Go outside  Good weather
7   B               Purpose     smt
```

I want to `group by` the values of `sentences` and create new `columns` when `Way` and `Purpose` exists in `entity` columns

Expected outcome:

```
   sentence entity      token                          Way       Purpose
0   A        Stay home  Severe weather, raining, Windy smt, SMTO Nan
1   B        Go outside Sunny, Good weather            Nan       smt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows for non matched rows by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `~` for invert mask, aggregate `join` and use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for filter rows matched list with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
vals = ['WAY','purpose']

m = df1['entity'].isin(vals)

df2 = df1[m].pivot_table(index='sentence',columns='entity',values='token', aggfunc=','.join)
df3 = df1[~m].groupby(['sentence','entity'])['token'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()

df = df3.join(df2, on='sentence')
print (df)
  sentence      entity                           token       WAY purpose
0        A   Stay home  Severe weather, raining, Windy  smt,SMT0     NaN
1        B  Go outside             Sunny, Good weather       NaN     smt
```